# Bootstrap aggregation (bagging) of logistic regression classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

So I'm taking N bootstrap samples and training N logistic regression classifiers on these samples. Each classifier gives me some probability of being in a binary class and then I average these N probabilities to get a final prediction.

My question is if I took the N sets of regression coefficients and averaged those and used that averaged set of coefficients in a logistic regression classifier and took the output probability as the final prediction, is this the same as taking the average of the resultant N probabilities as described in the previous paragraph?

Comment: Please stop cross-posting on here and on Cross validated. Cross validated is the best place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no because the logistic function is non-linear: `1/(1+exp(-a)) + 1/(1+exp(-b))` is not equal to `1/(1+exp(-(a+b)))`.

But the inverse of the logistic function (also called log-odds), is linear ([`g(x)` in this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function.2C_odds_ratio.2C_and_logit)). If you are calculating the log-odds, you can average the corresponding coefficients (`beta0` and `beta1` in the page) in your bagging procedure.